# How can std::chrono::duration::duration() be constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

The default constructor of `std::chrono::duration` is defined as follows:

`constexpr duration() = default;`

(For example, see [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration) or the libstdc++ source.)

However, [cppreference.com also says this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) about `constexpr` constructors:

> A constexpr constructor must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> ...
>
> **every base class and every non-static member must be initialized**, either in the constructors initialization list or by a member brace-or-equal initializer. In addition, every constructor involved must be a constexpr constructor and every clause of every brace-or-equal initializer must be a constant expression

And in case I was confused about default constructors, [cppreference.com seems to say](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) that default constructors brought into being with `= default` aren't defined differently than implicit default constructors.

Yet, the `rep` type for (most) durations is a bare integer type.  So, shouldn't the explicit `= default` default constructor for `duration` be equivalent to

`constexpr duration() {}`

which of course would leave the integer member variable of type `duration::rep`  uninitialized?  And, in fact, isn't the standard behaviour of `duration` such that default-constructed values *are* uninitialized?  (But I can't find a reference that explicitly says this.)

So how can the `= default` constructor for `duration` be `constexpr` if it leaves a non-static member variable uninitialized?  What am I missing?

Comment: I believe this means the implementers have to us in class initialization.

Comment: It's `constexpr` on a temploid, so even if the defaulted version doesn't satisfy the requirement of a constexpr constructor it's still OK - it just can't be used in constant expressions.

Comment: `duration::rep` is a type, not a member, isn't it?

Comment: @T.C. what's a templ*oid*?

Comment: @TemplateRex template-like things that are not templates (e.g., non-template member functions/classes of class templates).

Comment: @AndyG in the standard definition of `duration` it has a private member `rep rep_;  // exposition only` . I think it would satisfy the requirement if the real definition had an in-class initializer , or a default constructor of its own which initialized the object

Comment: The standard doesn't seem to say anything about what value `rep_` gets in the default construction case though, I guess it should be treated as *unspecified*

Comment: @AndyG: Yes, I clarified the wording to show I mean the member variable that must exist of type `duration::rep` but whose name is unspecified.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

7.1.5 The `constexpr` specifier [dcl.constexpr] says:

> The definition of a `constexpr` constructor shall satisfy the
> following requirements:
>
> - the class shall not have any virtual base classes;
> - for a defaulted copy/move constructor, the class shall not have a mutable subobject that is a variant member;
> - each of the parameter types shall be a literal type;
> - its function-body shall not be a function-try-block;
>
> In addition, either its function-body shall be = delete, or it shall
> satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - either its function-body shall be = default, or the compound-statement of its function-body shall satisfy the requirements
>   for a function-body of a constexpr function;
> - every non-variant non-static data member and base class sub-object shall be initialized (12.6.2);
> - if the class is a union having variant members (9.5), exactly one of them shall be initialized;
> - if the class is a union-like class, but is not a union, for each of its anonymous union members having variant members, exactly one of
>   them shall be initialized;
> - for a non-delegating constructor, every constructor selected to initialize non-static data members and base class sub-objects shall be
>   a constexpr constructor;
> - for a delegating constructor, the target constructor shall be a constexpr constructor.

In a nutshell, `= default` is a valid definition of a `constexpr` default constructor as long as the other requirements above are met.

So how does this work with *uninitialized* constructions?

It doesn't.

For example:

```
constexpr seconds x1{};
```

The above works and initializes `x1` to `0s`.  However:

```
constexpr seconds x2;

error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const seconds'
       (aka 'const duration<long long>') without a user-provided default
        constructor
    constexpr seconds x2;
                      ^
                        {}
1 error generated.
```

So to create a `constexpr` default constructed `duration`, you must *zero-initialize* it.  And the `= default` implementation allows one to zero-initialize with the `{}`.

Complete working demo:

```
template <class Rep>
class my_duration
{
    Rep rep_;
public:
    constexpr my_duration() = default;
};


int
main()
{
    constexpr my_duration<int> x{};
}
```

**Interesting Sidebar**

I learned something in writing this answer, and wanted to share:

I kept wondering why the following doesn't work:

```
using Rep = int;

class my_duration
{
    Rep rep_;
public:
    constexpr my_duration() = default;
};


int
main()
{
    constexpr my_duration x{};
}

error: defaulted definition of default constructor is not constexpr
        constexpr my_duration() = default;
        ^
```

Why does making this class a non-template break the `constexpr` default constructor?!

(*Update:*  This now compiles with C++20)

Then I tried this:

```
using Rep = int;

class my_duration
{
    Rep rep_;
public:
    my_duration() = default;  // removed constexpr
};


int
main()
{
    constexpr my_duration x{};
}
```

And the compilers like it again.

<del>If there isn't already a CWG issue on this, there probably should be.  The behavior seems a bit inconsistent.  And this is probably just because we (the entire industry) are still learning about `constexpr`.</del> Fixed in C++20.

Comment: But inside `constexpr` functions, you could do `constexpr auto fun() { seconds x2; x2 = seconds{}; return x2; }`, right?

Comment: @TemplateRex:  clang doesn't like it.  It complains about `x2`'s construction.  Even using something pretty close to tip-of-trunk and using `-std=c++1z`.

Comment: hmm, indeed. I misremembered some of my own code that did the 2-step initialization, but those classes had in-class initializers with `=default` on the constructor so they were actually `constexpr`.

Comment: I must not understand something about brace initialization.  It sounds like the `= default` ends up creating a constructor that does two different things.  If I call it without braces (or without ()?) it does no initialization, but if I call it with braces (or with ()?) then it _does_ initialize the member variable?  I don't quite follow that part.  A hand-written constructor like `my_duration() {}` doesn't work that way as far as I know, but you're saying `my_duration() = default` does?  Why?

Comment: @BradSpencer Yeah, for a non-aggregate, `S s{}` is *value-initialization* and `S s;` is *default-initialization*.  If `S` is a class with a defaulted default constructor then value-initialization zero-initializes before doing default-initialization.  If the constructor were `{}` instead of `= default` then the two cases would be the same (both leaving rep uninitialized). See [dcl.init]/8

Comment: @HowardHinnant the behaviour seems to suggest that clang's library uses `rep rep_;` whereas gcc's uses `rep rep_{};`  . If that is the case then does it mean `seconds s; cout << s.count();` is potentially undefined behaviour?  (`rep_` is an uninitialized variable in clang's version)

Comment: @BradSpencer:  Yes, that is essentially it.  The "why" is because the standard says so.  Why does the standard say so?  Not sure, I checked http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2346.htm and didn't immediately see a recorded rationale for this feature.  I like it because it gives the client the choice of speed (no initialization) vs zero initialization.

Comment: @M.M:  I don't recall if it is undefined or unspecified.  But yes, you can't count on what value will be printed.