# Why does clang, using libstdc++, delete the explicitly defaulted constructor on a type containing std::optional?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, clang++, libstdc++

Consider the following structure with an `std::optional` containing a type that definitely has a "normal" default constructor.

```
#include <optional>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    const std::optional<std::string> m_value;
};

bool function()
{
    Foo foo;
    return bool(foo.m_value);
}
```

Compiling the following with clang 9 (using the system's default `libstdc++`, for its gcc 8) gives an unexpected warning:

```
<source>:6:5: warning: explicitly defaulted default constructor is implicitly deleted [-Wdefaulted-function-deleted]
    Foo() = default;
    ^
<source>:7:38: note: default constructor of 'Foo' is implicitly deleted because field 'm_value' of const-qualified type 'const std::optional<std::string>' (aka 'const optional<basic_string<char> >') would not be initialized
    const std::optional<std::string> m_value;
                                     ^
```

There's also hard error for `Foo foo;` since it uses said deleted constructor.

- Deleting the `Foo() = default;` constructor gives the same results.
- Replacing it with `Foo() {}` works!
- Removing all the constructors and initializing `foo` as `Foo foo{};` works!
- Explicitly initializing the member as `const std::optional<std::string> m_value{};` works!
- Removing the `const` from the member works! (but isn't the same meaning)
- Using clang 9 with `-stdlib=libc++` works!
- Using gcc 8.3 (still with `libstdc++`) works!

I've read [std::optional - construct empty with {} or std::nullopt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964217) which seems to indicate that the `libstdc++` implementation choice of an `= default` constructor for `std::optional` is likely to blame.  But, in that question, the concern was a matter of efficiency of one approach vs. the other.  In this case, it seems like a matter of *correctness*.

(I suspect that the answer to [How can std::chrono::duration::duration() be constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36342296/693212) is going to be part of the story here.)

I see the same behaviour on Compiler Explorer: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Yj1o5P

Compare simple structures of optional and non-optional `std::string` (in the non-working configurations):

```
struct Foo { const std::optional<std::string> m_value; };
auto f1() { Foo f; return f.m_value; } // Fails: call to implicitly deleted constructor.

struct Bar { const std::string m_value; };
auto f2() { Bar b; return b.m_value; } // Works.
```

Is this a bug in `libstdc++`?  Is it mixed intentions and assumptions between clang and `libstdc++`?

Surely the intent can't be that I can have a structure with a `const std::string` but I can't have a structure with a `const std::optional<std::string>` unless I wrote a constructor?

(In real-word cases, you'd have additional constructors, too.  Thus the motivation for an `= default()` constructor in the first place.  That, and clang-tidy.)

Edit: Here's an expanded version of the example ([Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5bssGa)) showing a similar example working in "pure clang", "pure gcc", but failing in mixed "clang+libstdc++".  This slightly bigger example is still artificial, but hints at why one might want to actually have such a defaulted constructor.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default; // Implicitly deleted?!
    explicit Foo(std::string arg) : m_value{std::move(arg)} {}
    const auto& get() const noexcept { return m_value; }
  private:    
    const std::optional<std::string> m_value;
};

// Maybe return an empty or a full Foo.
auto function(bool flag, std::string x)
{
    Foo foo1;
    Foo foo2{x};
    return flag ? foo1 : foo2;
}
```

Comment: [`[dcl.init]/7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#7) is likely the culprit.

Comment: There's a compilation error with a `const int` member ([godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/69d3xK)), so the problem probably has to do with `= deafult` and `const` member variables.

Comment: `std::optional` has absolutely zilch to do with it. It is because of `const`.

Comment: @IlCapitano: I am not surprised that `const int value;` deletes the default constructor (since `int` lacks a constructor).  But seems like `const optional<T> value;` _should_ work, no matter what `T` is, especially when `const T value;` works.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Can you help me understand how it has nothing to do with `optional` when `const string x` works, but `const optional<string> x` doesn't work?  And why does "pure clang+libc++" work and "pure gcc+libstdc++" work, but "mixed clang+libstdc++" not work?

Comment: It looks like a bug in gcc to me. [see](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T97698) The library is a red herring, one has a `=default` default ctor and one has `{}`. I don't think the standard specifies it either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a combination of:

- an underspecification in the Standard;
- a suboptimal Library implementation; and
- a compiler bug.

Firstly, the Standard does not specify whether for the default [optional.ctor](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.ctor) a permissible implementation would be to defined it as defaulted:

```
constexpr optional() noexcept = default;
                              ^^^^^^^^^ OK?
```

Note that [functions.within.classes](http://eel.is/c++draft/functions.within.classes) answers the question in the affirmative for copy/move constructors, assignment operators, and non-virtual destructors, but does not mention default constructors.

This matters because it affects program correctness; on the assumption that `optional` has data members approximating the following:

```
template<class T>
class optional {
    alignas(T) byte buf[sizeof(T)]; // no NSDMI
    bool engaged = false;
    // ...
};
```

then since `buf` is a direct non-variant non-static data member lacking a default member initializer, if the default constructor of `optional` is defined as defaulted and thus is not user-provided, `optional` is not [const-default-constructible](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#def:const-default-constructible) and so `optional<A> const a;` is ill-formed.

It is thus a bad idea for a Library to define the default constructor of `optional` as defaulted, not only for this reason but also because it makes a value-initialized `optional<B> b{};` perform more work than necessary, since it must zero-initialize `buf`, as observed [std::optional - construct empty with {} or std::nullopt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964217/stdoptional-construct-empty-with-or-stdnullopt) - see in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58139141/567292). libstdc++ is fixed in [this commit](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=bafd12cb22e83b7da8946873513a897e48e2900f), which will be included in the next release of gcc, presumptively gcc 11.

Finally, it is a bug in gcc that it allows a non-const-default-constructible type for a `const` non-static data member without default member initializer of a class type whose default constructor is defined as defaulted; clang is correct to reject it. A [reduced testcase](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jhhY9q) is:

```
struct S {
    S() = default;
    int const i;
};
```

The best workaround in your case would be to supply a NSDMI:

```
const std::optional<std::string> m_value = std::nullopt;
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or (though I prefer the former, as it [gives better codegen](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3MTsEa) under Clang/libstdc++):

```
const std::optional<std::string> m_value = {};
                                         ^^^^
```

You might also consider giving `Foo` a user-defined default constructor; this [results in better codegen](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cfeWWW) under gcc (not zeroing the buffer but only setting the `engaged` member to `false`) thanks to what is presumably a related compiler bug.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. That all makes sense, and I like your advice for workarounds.